# Is it rude to wear a star and crescent if you're not muslim?

Tags: non-muslim, clothing, symbolism

I went to a store  called Spencers and bought a choker. I didn't  realize it was a star and crescent, used to symbolize Muslims and Iraq I believe. I'm sorry if I didn't get that right though. Anyway, it's a crescent moon with a star inside of it, just like the symbol.

Is it rude to wear this if I'm not Muslim?

Is it sort of like how people wear crosses when they aren't Christian? Someone please inform me of this, I don't want to offend anyone when in public.

Comment: It is not rude. You can wear them. There are no symbols of Islam,  albeit that the Turkish flag has a crescent and a star.

Answer (score 1):

**Islam has no symbol.**

The crescent with a star is an ancient symbol, which is used by a vast number of nations like Sumerians, Byzantium, Persians, Turks etc.

In short, there is nothing bad to wear it.

Answer (score 1):

That is just an ancient symbol that's used by different nations till today but it has nothing to do within Islam its just a cultural thing rather then religious. And yes you can wear it wherever you want  and NO you are not  offending anyone by doing this. I am sure people will ask you about it but not in wrong way. They just wanna to know how you came across this or how did you know about their culture.

Comment: This answer would benefit from references

Comment: I am gonna try to get the references for this.